# Second record doesnt get stored in arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, object, arraylist, store

I have an arraylist which the records are stored as  objects. 
In a different form i allow the user to enter an id and retrieve the data of that record with the corresponding id.

My problem is , i can only retrieve one record , meaning only the first record which i  store in the arraylist.

If i type in a second record and if try to search the record using the id , i get the message "invalid id", its the message which i assigned to make sure that users won't enter invalid ids.

Here is the code which i used to store the object in to the arraylist:-

```
patient_class patients=new patient_class(firstname,lastname,initials,gender,birthday,birthmonth,birthyear,contactnumber,address,bloodgroup,patientid);

           patientlist.add(patients);
```

Here is my code to check whether if the arraylist contains the id.

```
public boolean checkrecord(ArrayList<patient_class>patients,String search)
    {

         for(patient_class patient : patients)
         {
        if(patient.getid().contains(search))
        {
            return true;
        }

    }    
    return false;
    }
```

if the it is true i have the created a separate constructor to find the record for the give id.

Here is the code for that :-

```
public patient_class searchrecord(ArrayList<patient_class> patients, String search)
 {


        for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop


            if(patient.getid().equals(search))
            {

                return patient;

            }
        else
            {
            return null;
            }
        return null;
        }
```

Why can i only enter one record but not 2 records in to the arraylist ? My program display "succussfuly registered" when i enter the second record and click register, but i cant search that record , but i can delete the record using another method i made.

What am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
for(patient_class patient: patients) //used  enhanced for loop
    if(patient.getid().equals(search))
    {
        return patient;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
return null;
```

Due to your `else` block, you're returning `null` if the *first* patient doesn't match the patient you're looking for, instead of looking for other matches. You should get rid of the `else` block. I'd also add braces to make the control flow clearer:

```
for (patient_class patient : patients) {
    if (patient.getid().equals(search)) {
        return patient;
    }
}
// Only return null if we've checked *all* patients
return null;
```

Additionally, I'd *strongly* advise you to start following Java naming conventions, renaming `patient_class` to `Patient` and the `getid` method to `getId`:

```
for (Patient patient : patients) {
    if (patient.getId().equals(search)) {
        return patient;
    }
}
return null;
```

Comment: Thanks , got it working . Ill take the advice and change my variable names to a much more easy understanding names.